# Does any game make use of the Game Boy Serial Data Pin?

Tags: game-boy

On the original Game Boy (DMG) or the color version (CGB) is the Serial Data pin *ever* used by a retail game?

It is a middle pin on the link port.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about specific information about how data is transferred via the link cable.  That's more technical than we get for gaming expertise.  It's also a gaming recommendation, as we define them, which is also off-topic.

Comment: @Frank where would it be on topic? Electrical engineering?

Comment: @Frank also, how is this a game recommendation? It's asking for a verifiable list of games. Verifiable.

Comment: @Frank & AlexanderM - I'd reckon this is still on-topic as per *game specific hardware and utilities*, however Alex, you may get a more in-depth answer on the use of the pin elsewhere. That isn't to say that you *won't* get an answer here, but for once I'm stumped on exactly how one would check this easily. You'd have to hack together a rig that tests for current along the line as you work your way through the [games with link cable functionality](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Game_Boy_games_with_Link_Cable_functionality). It'd be an exhaustive process but not impossible.

Comment: @Robotnik This meets our criteria for a game recommendation quite easily.  What games use the serial data pin is asking for a list of games that meet a set of criteria.  Recommendation if ever I saw one.

Comment: @Frank - 'Do any X do Y' is a little different to 'List all X that do Y'. As long as there's one, it's a 'yes' answer - but like I said, finding 'one' might be difficult.

Comment: @Robotnik I can see your point of view, but I feel the comments show the asker is asking for a list of games that meet the criteria.  It doesn't solve the problem that answers aren't really going to complete, nor will they be objective; it's still going to be a popularity contest.

Comment: @Frank - I can see yours as well :). We've both stated our pieces so its up to other reviewer's judgements now. Either way it's an interesting query with an even more interesting problem space - @ Alex if this does get closed here I'd still be interested in reading up on it, comment the link if you end up asking it elsewhere :)

Comment: Perhaps this could be reworded to "what was the serial used for". A good answer would provide games that used it for example

Comment: @AlexanderM  I believe that it does, in fact, get used by some games, however **there is not enough information in the question to provide a proper answer**. Please clarify what you want to know, without making it too wordy.

Answer (score 6):

### The Game Link Cable

The most obvious candidate for this are games that use the Game Link Cable. Individually checking all of them would be an imposing task, but luckily we don't have to. A schematic drawing of the wiring of the 8-bit Game Link Cable shows us this:

```
Plug 1         Plug 2  
 SI ______  ______SI  
 SO ______><______SO  
 GND_____________GND  
 SC _____________ SC
```

There is no wiring for the SD pin. From this we can conclude that no games using the standard Game Link Cable will make use of this pin. This also rules out the Gameboy Printer and the four player connector as both connect using a standard cable.

### Other Candidates

This leaves us with more specialised hardware that connects using the Game Link port but does not use the Game Link Cable. Apart from the unreleased Work Boy there are only two options:

#### Game Boy Mobile Phone connector

Released in Japan only for use with some Pokémon games.

[image: Gameboy Mobile Phone connector]

#### Singer Izek 1500

An Game Boy-enabled embroidering machine. It has a built-in custom link cable and a custom game cartridge. The Game Boy is used to select different patterns and options.

[image: Singer Izek 1500]

Sadly I don't have access to either piece of hardware and thus can't tell what pins they use.

Comment: I really hope that sowing machine is off-topic. Why is there a GBC sowing machine!?

Comment: @AlexanderM Don't knock that Singer.  To GameBoy collectors, that thing is the "Holy Grail".  Sure, we may not be budding seamstresses (or seam-masters?) but it's one of the hardest licensed products to find as a complete set.